# How to create square of walls via WPF in Revit python

Tags: python, wpf, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I start learning pyRevit and  here's the trouble. I want to create a WPF where I may enter values then Revit could would automatically construct a simple rectangular building. I have already create a WPF but I'm stuck in part where I need to connect lenght's value(interface) with python code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoMLO.jpg)

```
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *
from pyrevit.forms import WPFWindow
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument


class ModalForm(WPFWindow):
    def __init__(self, xaml_file_name):
        WPFWindow.__init__(self, xaml_file_name)
        self.ShowDialog()

    def start_button(self, sender, e):
        levels = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
    walls = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()
        for level in levels:
            elevation = level.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.LEVEL_ELEV).AsDouble()
            if elevation == 1000/304.8:
                level_0 = level
        for wall in walls:
            name = wall.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SYMBOL_NAME_PARAM).AsString()
            if name == 'C25/30 - 250mm':
                wall_type = wall
        p_1 = XYZ(0,0,level_0.Elevation)
        p_2 = XYZ(50,0,level_0.Elevation)
        line_1 = Line.CreateBound(p_1, p_2)
    

        t = Transaction(doc, 'column')
        t.Start()

        wall_1 = Wall.Create(doc, line, wall_type.Id, level_0.Id, 3000/304.8, 0, False, True)
        t.Commit()
        self.Close()        

    def cancel_button(self, sender, e):
        self.Close()

form = ModalForm('interface.xaml')
```

Answer (score 1):

For the programmatic creation of a super simple building, please refer to The Building Coder little house sample:

- [Selecting all Walls](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/09/selecting-all-w.html)
- [Wall Dimensions](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/09/wall-dimensions.html)
- [Element Materials](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/10/element-materials.html)
- [AutoJoinElements](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/05/autojoinelements.html)
- [Validate Roof Type and View OBJ on Android](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/08/validate-roof-type-and-view-obj-on-android.html)
- [ADN Mesh Data Custom Exporter to JSON](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/07/adn-mesh-data-custom-exporter-to-json.html)   ^
- [Creating a Sloped Floor](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/03/creating-a-sloped-floor.html)
- [Calculating Gross and Net Wall Areas](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/calculating-gross-and-net-wall-areas.html)
- [Revit Answer Day and Creating a Roof](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/09/revit-answer-day-and-creating-a-roof.html)
- [Trusted Signature and Revit 2017 API Resources](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/08/trusted-signature-and-updated-revit-2017-api-resources.html)
- [Adding Custom Geometry to the Forge Viewer](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/03/adding-custom-geometry-to-the-forge-viewer.html)
- [ADN Xtra Labs and API Changes since Revit 2013](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/adn-xtra-labs-and-api-changes-since-revit-2013.html)